# Inserting timestamp in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

When I am inserting a time field in the database table, it inserts with a proper time and date in localhost and I can retrieve a correct time. BUT
The same code when I upload it in the server(Godaddy), the value in the database field will insert "30 minutes less than the actual time".

What may be the reason?

Comment: may be it is inserting server time

Comment: check your production server time.

Comment: Server time and Local time are same right ? OR Am I wrong ?

Comment: both can be different

Comment: How to check the Production server time?

Comment: local time is the time on your machine (assuming you are running the localhost in your computer)..server time means the time of the production server (GoDaddy)

Comment: have one file says `atime.php` and put `<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>` and run them both in your local machine and GoDaddy server.. note the time for both. You should see the server time and the time difference in your localhost and the server..

Comment: Yes now I got to know the time change betwenn local machine and server machine. How can I fix it now ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below to convert GoDaddy server time to Indian time.

```
$timestamp = strtotime($time) + 49000;
```

Where `$time` is the server production time and `$timestamp` is the new time generated.

Comment: Godday server is in USA so the time will insert as 14hours less than Indian time

Answer (score 1):

You just add this line at the top of your php file to set timezone....
Try this code:

```
<?php
   date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
   echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
 ?>
```

Comment: I added this. But the same problem exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Please Try this

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
  echo date_default_timezone_get(), '--', date("Y-m-d g:i:a"),'<br />';
?>
```

Comment: I added this. But the same problem exist.